# Android studio with sharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, android

Can I download a list of data from a site from sharepoint in a mobile application using android and manage this data? What should I use for this?

We need to use this sdk library:

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android

Comment: Have you checked the API information on Microsoft.com? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/choose-the-right-api-set-in-sharepoint

Comment: Yup. But I didn't see that the data can be returned by json-objects, but only return xml, as in these examples: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service